# Notifying Website w/Security Hole

Tags: penetration-test

As a hobby, I find security holes ranging from XSS to SQLi to LFI etc in random websites I find. (I don't exploit them). I've decided to to do a little more; I want to create a volunteer group composed of hackers who will find holes and report them to the website.

I'm finding two "issues":

- Although I don't exploit the holes, could I get in legal trouble for reporting the hole to the website?
- Where could I find fellow non-malicious hackers?

The group would be entirely volunteer based and would be completely non-malicious.We would not take on clients or do tests on request. Sites would be entirely random; no specific sites would be targeted and the test would be conducted without the site's consent or knowledge. If a hole is found, the site is notified. If not, we would move on.

Should I be concerned about anything else?

I apologize if this is the wrong site to ask, but I have no idea where to go...

Comment: I'm not a lawyer or a professional in the security field, but I imagine that that's a very bad idea.  Don't forget that legal problems don't only carry the chance of punishment.  Even a lawsuit in which your found non-liable can be expensive.  Also, I don't think you could find 'hackers' you trust enough.  A single bad act could bring rather bad attention to the entire group.

Comment: Simple, **don't notify them**,  you could be breaking the law.

Comment: Send an email to the webmaster from an anonymous email address, on a computer that you do not generally use. Make sure that the email provider does not log IP addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read the [latest IT Security's blog post](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2012/04/qotw-22-what-are-legalethical-concerns-to-bear-in-mind-when-hacking-websites-with-open-invitations/) which talks about a similar topic. It's a interesting read and you might find some answers, even if your scenario and the one they are analyzing are a bit different.

The point is, there are many possible consequences to bear in mind when hacking a website that requests to be hacked, if you want to hack a website that doesn't request to be hacked and then notify them, you should probably be even more careful.

Of course, I am no lawyer, so for any more specific questions I suggest you to talk to one.

Comment: Yeah, I also figured I should talk to a laywer, but I can't afford one... Any free/volunteer lawyers?

Comment: @MihirSingh a fast Google query return this link, maybe you could find it useful: http://www.freeadvice.com/

Comment: submitted a question... thanks. crossing my fingers now :)

Comment: @MihirSingh mark the question as accepted if you are happy with it, for future viewers ;)

Comment: @MihirSingh oh I forgot, accepting means clicking on the checkmark below the arrows on the left of the answer. I'm telling you this because I see that many users miss that.